# PHP: Why do I get syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE)?

Tags: php

PHP: Why do I get syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) on line 38? I'm trying to create a forum for the first time with php and mysql and I'm not sure what's wrong with my code.

```
<?php
session_start();
require"db_connect.php";

$sql = "SELECT forum_id, forum_name FROM forum_tbl";
if ($query = $db->prepare($sql)){
    $query->bind_result($f_id, $f_name);
    $query->execute();
    $query->store_result();
}else{
    echo $db->error;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<title>Forum</title>
<meta/>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
    <table align="center" width="80%">
        <?php
        if($query->num_rows !==0)
        while($row = $query->fetch())
        ?>  
        <tr>
        <td><a href="forum.php?id=<?php echo $f_id?>"><?php echo $f_name;?>    </a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile; endif;?>    
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't that `endif` out of place?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a `:` both for `if` and `while`. it should be

```
if($query->num_rows !==0):
while($row = $query->fetch()):
```

See the `:`s at end?

Read more about [PHP Alternate Control structure syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).